# Excel: INDEX MATCH with partial number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a large table of 12 digit numbers and associated info

I have a small list of 10 and 11 digit numbers (the first and/or last digits were cut off) - I'm attempting to cross these two lists to identify the items on the small list

normally, I'd use an index match to bring the associated info out of the table into the list, but because today I have only partial numbers in my list, I can't get the formula to work

I've seen other examples here that search for partial text strings contained within a range, but I haven't been able to adapt those formulas to my data. wildcards don't seem to work with numbers.

Many thanks for your input, and apologies in advance if I failed to find an existing solution on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match partial numbers inside a number range, like you do with strings, you can use an array formula with `INDEX/MATCH`, by composing a temporary array that converts the numbers into strings.

Say column `A` is your 12 digit numbers column, and you want to match the sequence `1234567890` and retrieve the value from column `B`, This **CSE formula** works:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9999, MATCH("*1234567890*",""&$A$2:$A$9999,0))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Although you can use full columns `A:A` and `B:B`, this should be avoided as much as possible with array formulas, because they're *slow*. Full columns mean computing and operating arrays of more than a million entries, so avoid it. Also note the "expensive" conversion from numbers to strings (all numbers in the `$A$2:$A$9999` are converted to strings here).

[image]

---

To use a cell reference, say `D2`, instead of the harcoded `1234567890`, the formula should be used like this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9999,MATCH("*"&D2&"*",""&$A$2:$A$9999,0))
```

Comment: Can this formula be adapted to use cell references? I tried the following without success: =INDEX($B$2:$B$9999, MATCH("*D2*",""&$A$2:$A$9999,0))

I have about 1000 10 and 11 digit sequences I need to match against my 12 digit numbers column

Comment: @CarlosDiaz dont enclose the reference with quotes. `MATCH("D2",...` ---> `MATCH("*"&D2&"*",...`

Comment: @CarlosDiaz See last added part in the answer for more details.