# Smallest value in column with index-match looking for partial match in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just found a solution to [find a partial match in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980145/excel-index-match-with-partial-number/54516854#54516854) (Thanks @A.S.H). The key formula is this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9999,MATCH("*"&D2&"*",""&$A$2:$A$9999,0))
```

I am now struggling to combine this with below code, which aims to find the 3rd smalles value in a column.

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Table1[ID]=[@[ID]];IF(Table1[Date]="";"";Table1[Date]));3);"")}
```

So I have a few times where the `[@[ID]]` (e.g. "123456") is part of a string in `Table1[ID]` (e.g. "123456; 654321").

Any idea how I could do this? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting an error? would it be due to the separator being ";" instead of "," ? or vice versa?

Comment: I get a #NUM error if I try: `{=SMALL(IF(""&Table1[ID]="*"&[@[ID]]&"*";IF(Table1[Date]="";"";Table1[Date]));3)}`

The ";" instead of "," has to do with my version & language setting of Excel and is not causing this.

Comment: It is confusing since you show both the , and the ; in your examples: only one will work on your system...

Comment: The first code is just a copy of A.S.H.'s solution, didn't bother to update the , to ;